# Java - Rounding off 2 decimal places

Tags: java, io, decimal

Lets say i have an user input. The class standing has a total of 80 and the exam is 100. But how do i round the result off to two decimal places?

```
System.out.print("Grades = 50% Class Standing + 50% Exams = " + (cs/160+exam/200)*100);
```

Comment: Look at `String#format`

Comment: what are the data types of cs and exam? Beware integer division!

Comment: They are declared as doubles

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.printf(
    "Grades = 50%% Class Standing + 50%% Exams = %.2f%n", (cs/160+exam/200)*100);
```

The `%.2f` specifier indicates that the float/double should be rounded to two decimal places. `%n` is a new line.

Also note that we have to escape literal `%`s with another `%` (i.e. `%%`) so that they are not mistaken for format specifiers.

Comment: It says that i have an exception which is about conversion? Is there a certain import i must include in the program?

Comment: @user3360708 See the edit -- I forgot to escape the other `%` symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The BigDecimal class will give you what you need.  You can set the precision as well as the rounding strategy, see here:

http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial